# Is one statement in MySQL running as a transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a statement like

```
replace into a(A,B,C,D,E) select * from b;
```

I don't know whether it runs as a transaction.

And is each DML statement in MySQL run as a transaction?

I have tried the statement below to produce a duplicate key error and it runs as a transaction.

```
insert into a select * from b;
```

However, I am not sure if one statement in any case runs as a transaction.

Comment: Statements are atomic, you can't execute half statement if that's what you mean. This is unrelated to transactions.

Comment: *And is each DML statement in MySQL run as a transaction?* There is only one DML statement in MySQL which is not a single transaction, and this is LOAD DATA. Formally TRUNCATE TABLE is not a transaction too - but it locks the table exclusively, so nothing can interfere with it.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for mentioning the LOAD DATA case! To make it clear to other readers: TRUNCATE TABLE is a DDL statement and not a DML [TRUNCATE explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html#:~:text=Although%20TRUNCATE%20TABLE%20is%20similar,one%2C%20particularly%20for%20large%20tables.).
"Although TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to DELETE, it is classified as a DDL statement rather than a DML statement."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html says:

> In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If `autocommit` mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own.